# In Processing web service data, Why m.prop is not required?

Tags: mithril.js

> Note that this getter-setter holds an undefined value until the AJAX
>   request completes.

```
var users = m.prop([]); //default value
var doSomething = function() { /*...*/ }
m.request({method: "GET", url: "/user"}).then(users).then(doSomething)
```

---

But  following code is not used m.prop. Why?

Are you set the default value in a different way?

```
//model
var User = {}

User.listEven = function() {
    return m.request({method: "GET", url: "/user"}).then(function(list) {
        return list.filter(function(user) {return user.id % 2 == 0});
    });
}

//controller
var controller = function() {
    return {users: User.listEven()}
}
```

---

If ok in the above code, and useless in the following?

```
var doSomething = function() { /*...*/ }
m.request({method: "GET", url: "/user"}).then(doSomething)
```

https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.request.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `listEven` code works because both `m.prop` and `m.request` returns a `GetterSetter`, but when using `m.request` the `GetterSetter` will be populated with the value returned from the promise. It's quite convenient.

And in the last example there is no `GetterSetter` involved, it's a simple promise usage. So all three examples works fine. To decide which one is best, you have to look at your specific case.